# AngularJS navbar page content

Tags: html, angularjs, navbar

Trying to learn AngularJS. I need to get working navigation bar, but I cant understand how to get content on each page.

Main HTML:

```
<html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">

<p>
<a href="#/">Main</a>
<a href="#about">About</a>
</p>

<div ng-view></div>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "index.html"
    })
    .when("/about", {
        templateUrl : "about.html"
    })
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

about.html

```
<h1>London</h1>
<h3>London is the capital city of England.</h3>
<p>It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I cant understand how to get content on each page. Like I call about.html and I want to get that page content.

Comment: Everything seems ok. If you click About button, the content of about.html should be included to you main html. Be sure that your templateUrl is correct.

Comment: change `<a href="#about">About</a>` to `<a href="#/about">About</a>`

Comment: still not working.
should i need to add some head/body also to about.html or it is enough with content info?

Comment: do you inject js files??

Comment: Only script I have is on index.html

Comment: Post your *complete* main html file. Tell us what the complete addess is in the address bar of the browser. Tell us if you have an error in your browser console, and if so, what it says.

Comment: Complete main.html is on me post.
Index file: file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/Angular/index.html
about file: file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/Angular/index.html#/about

Comment: You can't use the router when serving your app from the file system directly. The router needs to send AJAX requests to get the templates, an that can only work over HTTP. Use a web server to serve your web app.

Comment: what other ways is to make SPA (Single Page Application)?

Comment: I have a script, that calls ajax.

Comment: There is no AJAX call in your code other than the ones made by the router. If you make an AJAX call by yourself, it will fail, too. You're creating a **web** app. You shouldn't be afraid of serving it over the protocol of the web, http, using a web server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137827/discussion-between-elly-and-jb-nizet).